# which unix or linux command is used to change root password of remote machine(Just an IP address) without using SSH Login

Tags: linux, ssh, security

which unix or linux command is used to change root password of remote machine(Just an IP address)?

Suppose I just have an IP address of the target machine which is on my network, But I do not know root password of this machine, Is there any command available in Linux or unix that allow me to change root password that target machine, So that after changing the root password of the target machine I can do ssh to login into the target machine with new root password.

Comment: Something that makes security meaningless?

Comment: Also posted at http://superuser.com/questions/735204/which-unix-or-linux-command-is-used-to-change-root-password-of-remote-machineju

Comment: @devnull But is there package or script available like a concept of sshnuke(Demostrated in one of hollywood movie).

Comment: Consider asking the director of the movie then `:)`

Answer (score 2):

There is no such command.

Consider that if you could remotely access and change protected files on a remote host, you *already* have the powers of the superuser on that host, so changing the root password would be pointless.  In fact it would be worse than pointless because it would be an obvious indicator that the host was compromised.

Comment: But consider it in term of ethical hacking , Suppose we get news about breach or leakage of root password and someone already changed it, and now he is owning my system. Now I want to get back access to our system by applying same concept to change root password and then gain access to it back. What is the best way to do this then?

Comment: @SunilSingh you will have to get physical access to the machine.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no program that works the way that you describe. If there were, it would need to be on both machines and would be a security vulnerability.

The closest option would be to remotely execute `passwd`, but you would need to know the root password, or at least have a ssh key in your authorized hosts.

```
ssh root@foo -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa passwd 
(current) UNIX password:
...
```

Comment: But consider it in term of ethical hacking , Suppose we get news about breach or leakage of root password and someone already changed it, and now he is owning my system. Now I want to get back access to our system by applying same concept to change root password and then gain access to it back. What is the best way to do this then?

Comment: If you have ssh keys setup, and the hacker hasn't wiped them, you could still get in. Otherwise Disconnect it from the network, and physically login to the machine under single user mode. Though if it has been compromised, you shouldn't put it back in production without a format first.